# python with multi reg match and cost many time?

Tags: python

I have many title and a title Reg Rule List.
I need to use each reg to match each tile.

If the the length of Reg Rule List <=512,it cost me 1 second.

But if the the length of Reg Rule List >512,it cost me 50 second.

Why this happen?

I try to split Reg Rule List to multi list and each <500,but the problem still exite.

this is my code

```
 for MatchTitle in TitleList:
     for RegList in RegListList:
        for Reg in RegList:
            if re.match('.*' +Reg + '.*', MatchTitle):
                ThisReg= True #some prosess
```

Comment: Sorry I can barely understand this. 'reg' means 'regex'? You are trying to compare and match (many) multiple regexes against each title. First, there's no need for `re.match('.*' +Reg + '.*',` , that's hugely inefficient, just use `re.search(Reg, ...` instead.

Comment: Next, **give us at least 10 examples of your regexes, and 10 examples of your titles**. If the regexes are non-overlapping, or have some shared base prefix, then we can easily partition them out (think of like a binary-tree), splitting on the first few chars. That should boost you enormously. But you need to give us real example data. Or else this question will get downvoted and closed.

Comment: Also, each string could hit multiple regexes. Do you care about that scenario, that we have to <perform action> for each matching regex?

Comment: Also it's not obvious which variable corresponds to "Reg Rule List", is it `RegList` or `RegListList`?  Whichever it is, is there something different about Reg Rule number 512?  Or is it the same result regardless of order?  A complete runnable example would be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

A couple of suggestions:

1. A limited number of regexes is cached by the Python interpreter, so once that number is exceeded, every regex needs to be recompiled. That will cause a serious performance hit, although the number of cached regexes is (to my knowledge) closer to 100 than to 500. Better compile all the regexes beforehand explicitly.
2. Your use of `re.match()` is strange and probaby not quite doing what you think. If you use `re.search()` instead, you don't need the leading `.*` (because only `re.match()` anchors the regex to the start of the string). You don't ever need the trailing `.*`. Furthermore, `.*` only works if there are no linebreaks between the start of the string and the part that you want to match. And if your regex contains ungrouped alternations, there will be unexpected results.

   For example, if `reg` is `a|b`, then your regex `.*a|b.*` would match a string that *contains* an `a` after any number of non-linebreak characters or that *starts with* `b`.